# How can I query from multiple Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I wanted to query data from multiple sheets but couldn't find the correct formula. I used the below formula and it worked fine with querying from one sheet.

```
=QUERY('2022'!A1:S38, "Select B,H where R='N' and S=TRUE order by H")
```

Then I used the below formula hoping that I could derive the information from 2 sheets but it didn't work. Appreciate if someone could help me on this

```
=QUERY({'2022'!A1:S38;'2023'!A1:S38}, "Select B,H where R='N' and S=TRUE order by H")
```

Comment: This isn't jQuery. Please tag carefully.

Answer (score 0):

use `Col` references:

```
=QUERY({'2022'!A1:S38; '2023'!A1:S38}, 
 "select Col2,Col8 
  where Col18='N' 
    and Col19=TRUE 
  order by Col8")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes I tried this already just a short while ago and it worked. :)